# How do I convert a perl program into an installable module?

Tags: perl, module, bioperl

I have a perl program that I want to convert into a bioperl module. How do I do that? Is there an up-to date tutorial? That's really all I need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For module naming conventions and other information (whether you're writing it for CPAN or not), start with [`perlnewmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnewmod.html). To make an actual module, first install [`Module::Starter`](http://search.cpan.org/~xsawyerx/Module-Starter-1.71/lib/Module/Starter.pm) and use [`module-starter`](http://search.cpan.org/~xsawyerx/Module-Starter-1.71/bin/module-starter) command line utility to create your skeleton.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you! I just have a question. Would this be the correct format?: sudo module-starter --module=Bio::DB::CCDS \ --dir=/usr/share/perl5/Bio/DB/    It says --dir is unparseable

Comment: Just leave the optional `dir` param blank. Except for non-standard installs (which I'm almost certain you don't want), setting `--module` takes care of everything by default.

Comment: To further, for a basic case, I just set `--author`, `--email`, `--license` and `--module`